# Please explain Memory Leakage in Managed Code with example?

Tags: c#

I was asked this question in an interview: How does memory leakage problem occur in C# as of all know Garbage Collector responsible for all the memory management related work? So how is it possible?

Comment: I believe that many Components must still be closed/disposed explicitly in order to free up their resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318263):-

> **A memory leak occurs when memory is allocated in a program and is
>   never returned to the operating system, even though the program does
>   not use the memory any longer.** The following are the four basic types of memory leaks:
>
> - In a manually managed memory environment: Memory is dynamically    allocated and referenced by a pointer. The pointer is erased before the memory is freed. After the pointer is erased, the memory can no longer be accessed and therefore cannot be freed.
> - In a dynamically managed memory environment: Memory is disposed of    but never collected, because a reference to the object is still active. Because a reference to the object is still active, the garbage collector never collects that memory. This can occur with a  reference that is set by the system or the program.
> - In a dynamically managed memory environment: The garbage collector    can collect and free the memory but never returns it to the operating system. This occurs when the garbage collector cannot move the  objects that are still in use to one portion of the memory and free  the rest.
> - In any memory environment: Poor memory management can result when    many large objects are declared and never permitted to leave scope. As a result, memory is used and never freed.

```
 Dim DS As DataSet
  Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=SSPI")
  cn.Open()

  Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employees", cn)
  Dim i As Integer
  DS = New DataSet()

  For i = 0 To 1000
      da.Fill(DS, "Table" + i.ToString)
  Next
```

Although this code is obviously inefficient and not practical, it is meant to demonstrate that if objects are added to a collection (such as adding the tables to the DataSet collection), the objects are kept active as long as the collection remains alive. If a collection is declared at the global level of the program, and objects are declared throughout the program and added to that collection, this means that even though the objects are no longer in scope, the objects remain alive because they are still being referenced.

You may also check this reference:-

- [Identify And Prevent Memory Leaks In Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx)

The above link gives a very good conclusion

> Although .NET reduces the need for you to be concerned with memory,
>   you still must pay attention to your application's use of memory to
>   ensure that it is well-behaved and efficient. **Just because an
>   application is managed doesn't mean you can throw good software
>   engineering practices out the window and count on the GC to perform
>   magic.**

Answer (score 2):

Just holding on to a reference to an object when you actually don't have any use for it anymore is a good way to leak.  Particularly so when you store it in a *static* variable, that creates a reference that lives for the life of the AppDomain unless you explicitly set it back to null.  If such a reference is stored in a collection then you can get a true leak that can crash your program with OOM.  Not usual.

Such leaks can be hard to find.  Particularly events can be tricky that way, they will get the event source object to add a reference to the event handler object when you subscribe an event handler.  Hard to see in C# code because you never explicitly pass *this* when you subscribe the event.  If the event source object lives for a long time then you can get in trouble with all of the subscriber objects staying referenced.

The tricky ones do require a memory profiler to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

**Example** would be a Class `Child` containing `ClickEventHandler` method  subscribed to an Event `ClickEvent` of another class `Parent`.

`GC` of `Child` class would be blocked until `Parent` class goes out of scope..Even if `Child` goes out of scope it won't be collected by GC until `Parent` goes out of scope

---

All such subscribers subscribing to a Broadcaster(`Event`) would not be collected by GC until the broadcaster goes out of scope.

So, its a one way relation

```
Broadcaster(ClickEvent) -> Subscribers(ClickEventHandler)
```

GC of all the `ClickEventHandlers` would be blocked until `ClickEvent` goes out of scope!

Answer (score 0):

As example:

You have application with main form and static variable Popups[] collectionOfPopups. 
Store all application popups objects into static array and never delete them.

So with each new popup will take memory and GC will never release it.

Try to read how GC works
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

This will explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons, but here is one:

Consider two classes:

```
class A
{
  private B b;
}

class B
{
  private A a;
}
```

If you create an object for each of those classes, and cross-link them, and after that both those objects go out of the scope, you will still have link to each of them within another one. It is very difficult for GC to catch these sorts of crosslinks, and it may continue to believe that both objects are still in use.

Comment: The garbage collector has no trouble with circular references.

Comment: If there are no reachable references left to either the instance of A or B they will be collected. The .NET GC does not count references but determines reachability instead.